# How to redirect to external url from service class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my current spring project, I am adding several pairs of classes (controller/service) to provide payment option through several payment services. Each one of this classes have a structure like that:

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "pagseguro")
public class pagseguroPaymentController extends paymentController<Pagseguro> {
    ...
    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "comprar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void comprar(String payerId, String guid) throws Exception {
        this.payment.comprar(payerId, guid);
    }
    ...
}
```

**service**

```
@Service
public class pagseguroPaymentService extends paymentService<Pagseguro> {
  ...
  @Override
  public void comprar(String payerId, String guid) throws Exception {
    ...
    String response = checkout.register(null, false);
  }
  ...
}
```

in the method `comprar` from service class, I need redirect the application to an URL stored in a String variable (`response` in the example above).

My initial idea is use the library `java.net` from Java and create a utilitary class like that:

```
public class Redirect {
    public static String url;

    public static void redirect() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Anyone can give me a hint about how to accomplish that?

Comment: Any redirection should be done in the `@Controller`, not in service. You should send a notification from service and maybe the URL to redirect to the `@Controller` and perform the redirection there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform a simple redirection, you can inject the `HttpServletResponse` in your Controller layer:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "comprar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void comprar(String payerId, String guid, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    this.payment.comprar(payerId, guid);
}
```

And then simply do a redirect using that object:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://newUrl");
```

Now - as the Luiggi mentions in the comment - I would not do the redirect itself in the service layer, but rather return a boolean which decides if the redirect needs to be done - and then do it here, in the controller layer.

Hope it helps.